# Object required for WorksheetFunction

Tags: excel, vba, object, worksheet-function

I've got a user form with 2 drop down lists, and I'm using the values of these lists in a formula to display the results to the user. I'm having issues storing the formula result in a variable and displaying that in a message box. I have the bit of code below, but it throws an "Object required" error. I have seen some examples of formulas that put the result in a cell, but I don't need my value displayed anywhere except for the message box. Any ideas on what is causing my code to fail?

```
Dim selBranch As String
Dim selSkillTitle As String
Dim result As Variant

selBranch = frmQuery.cboBranch.Value
selSkillTitle = frmQuery.cboSkillTitle.Value

result = WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(skill_prof, branch, selBranch, skill_title, selSkillTitle)

MsgBox "Query Result" & vbNewLine & "--------------" & vbNewLine & _
    "Branch: " & branch & vbNewLine & _
    "Skill Level: " & skillTitle & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    "Average Skill Proficiency: " & CStr(result), vbInformation
```

`skill_prof`, `branch`, and `skill_title` are all named ranges in my workbook.

Comment: What line throws the error? And where did you `Set` those range variables?

Comment: The 'result =' line throws the error. I never set those range variables, I was thinking Excel would know that they're named ranges, but guessing that's not right =D

Comment: If they are named ranges than you need to handle them as such `Range("Named Range")`

Comment: Your guess is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(....)` would expect some range variables instead of non-declared empty variables.

You mentioned they are named ranges, therefor you need the right syntax to refer to them, possibly doing so in multiple ways, here is one:

```
Dim skill_prof as range: Set skill_prof = Worksheets("WhicheverSheet").Range("skill_prof")
'Etc
```

The above will make sure you can use the same formula in your code. Just make sure these named ranges are **equal sized** =)

Comment: Thanks! This does work (I get a result for the variable when I step through), however I get a type mismatch on the msgbox line, even if I declare result as a string and do CStr on the worksheet.function line. I was thinking everything in a msgbox had to be a string?

Comment: Nevermind the above...I see what I did wrong. Thanks for your answer, this works great.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a string @Sudio. The variable is a number, just concatenate it as such. `... & Result`